# Adding HTML Text the right way in Experience editor

Tags: sitecore

Our content author is more comfortable using Experience editor than the content editor and also has knowledge of HTML.
The requirement is - the author should also be able to add text  - along with other components (carousel, banner, etc), or just create a whole HTML page using Rich text editor if they need to.

For eg: He will open Experience editor of a page, add a banner component and then below the banned wants to add text. (or maybe just design the whole page using HTML)

I'm handling this kind of task for the first time and here is what I did.

Create the following:
1. A template with the name "Rich Text Section", which has one field "Content" of type "Rich Text".
2. A View Rendering, "Rich Text Component", that points to a .cshtml which is a simple HTML

```
<div class="row">
      @Html.Sitecore().Field("Content", Model)
   </div>
```

3. A folder "Rich Text Sections" under Sitecore > Content > Home > Components. In this folder, the author can add only "Rich Text Section" templates.

To add text to/or design a page, the author needs to do the following.

1. Browse in content editor mode. Add a new item (say "LoremIpsum"), of template type "Rich Text", inside the "Rich Text Sections" folder.
2. Browse in Experience editor mode. Add the "Rich Text Component", set its data source to "LoremIpsum", and then write all the HTML content inside.

Here, the author has to switch to both editor modes. Please advise the better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the `Insert Options` set up correctly on the items in your solution, then from the Experience Editor you can use `Insert Page` from the **Home** tab on Ribbon. This will then pop up a modal showing all the *Templates* that have been configured as `Insert Options`, the same ones as if you were to right click on a node in the *Content Editor* and select the *Insert* option.

[image: Insert Page]

The page will be created as a child of the page you are currently on. You can navigate to different sections of the content tree by enabling the `Navigation Bar` option from the **View** Ribbon, selecting the page and selecting *"Go"*.

[image: Navigate Pages]

---

EDIT: I mis-read your question. It seems you are trying to create the Datasource of the item when a component is added using the Experience Editor.

You need to set the `Datasource Location` and `Datasource Template` fields on the definition item of your Rendering:

[image: Datasource Location and Template Type]

Make sure you leave the `Data source` field empty on the Rendering item. Now when you add the component you will be prompted to `Select the Associated Content`. Your editors will be able to select existing content or create new ones.

[image: Select Associated Content]

You can read more in this [blog post](https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2015/03/17/prompt-user-to-selectcreate-datasource-item-when-inserting-rendering-via-page-editor/).